# Achar diferença entre duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql

Queria montar uma instrução sql que retornasse diferenças entre duas tabelas.

Por exemplo, tenho a tabela `arquivos` e a tabela `conferencias` onde possui campos iguais chamado `titulo` e `valor`, se em algum título aparecer valor diferente comparado com as duas tabelas ,preciso tratar isso como uma diferença.

```
    ARQUIVOS        | CONFERENCIAS
    ID TITULO VALOR | ID TITULO VALOR  
    1  0018    12    | 1  001    12  
    2  0026    20    | 2  002    20  
    3  0032    50    | 3  003    48 
    4  0047    120   | 4  004    120
```

Na tabela `arquivos` o nº do titulo vem com um numero a mais no final, sendo assim tem algum jeito de considerar só os três primeiros dígitos?

No exemplo acima a diferença  está no título 003 ou seja, o valor da diferença seria 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazendo um `INNER JOIN`, você consegue retornar a diferença de valor, comparando o `titulo` e o próprio `valor` nas duas tabelas.

```
SELECT * FROM ARQUIVOS a
INNER JOIN CONFERENCIAS b ON a.titulo = b.titulo AND a.valor <> b.valor
```

Como na sua tabela `ARQUIVOS` o campo `titulo` vem com um digito a mais, você poderia fazer o `SELECT` utilizando a função [`substr`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) do `MySQL`:

```
SELECT * FROM ARQUIVOS a
INNER JOIN CONFERENCIAS b ON SUBSTR(a.titulo, 1, 3) = b.titulo AND a.valor <> b.valor
```

Comment: Deu certo sim amigo, mas esqueci só de uma observação na minha pergunta, acabei de editar poderia ver?

Comment: Editei minha resposta, dê uma olhada